# jQuery get raw text (unescaped) for further parsing via underscore templates

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js

I currently have an html modal block like so:

```
<div id="modal">
   <div class="header_buttons"></div>
   <p> 
       Are you sure you would like to perform <%= action_name %> 
       on <%= count %> objects?
   </p>
   <div class="footer_buttons">
        <button>Do <%= action_name %></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to parse this content through `_.template`

```
$("#modal").html() //-> escapes `<%` 
$("#modal").text() //-> doesn't escape, but doesn't include tags.
```

My immediate solution is to target each element instead of the whole block so that I can use `text()` but I'm curious if there's an obvious solution here otherwise?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution you see a lot is to put HTML embedded templates in script tags, which are not HTML escaped.

So transforming your `div` into:

```
<script id="modal" type="text/template">
   ...
</script>
```

...would make `$("#modal").html()` return the raw HTML.

Of course if there's some reason you need it to be in a `div`, then this isn't for you.

Comment: That's the way. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: It does need to be a div to trigger the modal but I like it! I wonder how I can use this while making it work with a modal plugin (using bootstrap-modal).

Comment: You could just put the templates outside the modal and then render the html in the modal before opening it.  `$('#modal').html(rendered).modal()` or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `.html()`, then search and replace your template tags:

```
$("#modal").html().replace(/&lt;%=/g, '<%=').replace(/%&gt;/g, '%>');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PwL7L/

Comment: And what happens when the template contains an `id` attribute?

Comment: I'm using this but converting all `<%` to capture `_` javascript blocks

Comment: @muistooshort - Care to explain what you mean by that? How would that affect any of this?

Comment: If the template has an `id` attribute and the template is stored inside a `<div>`, you'll end up with two elements in the DOM with the same `id` attribute. You now have invalid HTML and you can expect strange things to happen with certain id selectors.

Comment: @muistooshort - Oh! That comment should have been on the question, not on the answer...

Comment: Probably should have been on both :) That's one of the reasons that templates always go inside `<script>` elements.

Comment: @muistooshort - let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15218/discussion-between-joseph-silber-and-mu-is-too-short)

Answer (score 1):

[_.unescape](http://underscorejs.org/#unescape) should help you use div instead of script.

> _.unescape($("#modal").html());